# how do you do something after a certain time has passed?

Tags: javascript, time

i'm trying to make an alarm in JS where i get the value of an input and Multiply it by 1000 to get the ms value and setTimeout a function which changes a paragraph element to become Time Up, the time in the setTimeout is the value of the input x 1000 (because miliseconds) Somewhat like this:

```js
function domChanger() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Time Up";
}
function time(alert) {
  alert = document.getElementById("input")
  alert.value *= 1000;
  setTimeout(domChanger(), alert.value)

}
```

instead of doing the expected for me (doing the function after the time set by alert.value * 1000 has passed) it instantly outputs Time Up. am I misunderstanding anything? because I searched on Google for like 1 hour and I couldn't find anything aside from setTimeout and setInterval.

Comment: Just remove the brackets on domChanger in your setTimeout call, otherwise instead of passing the function to setTimeout your calling it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the time as parameter. Just do the code bellow.

**HTML**

```
<p id="paragraph"></p>
<input type="number" id="input">
<button onclick="time()">Lauch domChanger</button>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
function domChanger() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Time Up";
}

function time() {
  alert = document.getElementById("input");
  alert.value *= 1000;
  setTimeout(domChanger, alert.value);;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is

```
setTimeout(domChanger(), alert.value)
```

where `domChanger()` is executed immediatly

you need to pass function reference

```
 setTimeout(domChanger, alert.value)
```

demo

```js
function domChanger() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Time Up";
}
function time() {
  var alert = document.getElementById("input")
  alert.value *= 1000;
  setTimeout(domChanger, alert.value)
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph"></p>
<input id="input" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="2">
<button type="button" onclick="time()">time</button>
```

Comment: @Keith right! I have updated my response. thanks

Comment: ty for the answer, but speaking of the solution gives me a question: how do you get there to be an argument when calling the function (if you need one)

Comment: @supasiblings `setTimeout(domChanger.bind(null, myArgument), alert.value);`